# CSS property indentation in Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Does anyone know if there is a way to change the default 2 space indentation for CSS properties to 4 spaces.

For example. From this:

```
div {
  color: red;
}
```

To this:

```
div {
    color: red;
}
```

As of right now I have to reindent all my copy/pasted code.

=================================================================

Update:

I'm using Pycharm, but remember I'm migrating styles from Devtools (copy/paste). I'm NOT composing my CSS in Pycharm. I could see configuring the tab character to be 2 or 4 spaces in Pycharm then, but this isn't the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the name of the stylesheet in the top-right corner, it will jump you to the source code. From here it will match your indentation: 2 spaces, 4 spaces, 8 spaces, etc. This is actually better than being able to configure whitespace indentation, because you can have variable indentation if you are working with media queries. Also, your webpage will update on the fly if you're making adjustments to your CSS.

Answer (score -1):

I'll say it depends on the application you are using to write your codes....

For example if it were to be in sublime text you would have to edit the script... 
I'll like to know which application you are using???

Comment: I'm talking about pasting the correct amount of whitespace from the copied text